# Python/Kivy: Changing attributes of dynamically created widgets

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Im trying to write a program that dynamically creates buttons with ids and is, by clicking on these buttons, able to change the texts on them.

Here is a simple version on what I hope to do:

```
def on_pre_enter():
   mylist = ['one','two','three']
   i = 1

   while(i != 3):

      button = CustomButton()
      button.text = "old text"
      button.id = mylist[i]

      button.bind(on_press =lambda x, z=z:self.callback( mylist[i],self ))
   
   self.manager.get_screen("myScreen").ids.parentID.add_widget(button)
   
   i=i+1
```

This creates the three buttons for me with the desired text. Now on the callback function I want them to change their own text. The callback should returns to me the list[i].(I can use/print it)

```
def callback(some, returnedLISTentry,self):

   self.ids.returnedLISTentry.text = "New text"

   #*other things with returnedLISTentry*
```

Other things with that returned list entry work fine.
I get this error, which I guess means that it cant find the id.

> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

I think I don't understand how kivy ids work. Im not sure if Im making the mistake while assigning or while trying to call the id.

I hope my mistake is not super obvious and thank you in advance to everyone!

Comment: Is the code you showed in your question whithin a class? If so show the code of the whole class

Comment: The `ids` dictionary in a class instance is built during the evaluation of a `kv` rule. Assigning an `id` attribute to a widget in python code will not result in its inclusion in the `ids`.

Comment: There are a few typos in your code:  `button = CustomButton` should probably be `button = CustomButton()` because without parentheses it's the class type but you probably mean to instantiate the class, the definition of callback needs a colon (`:`) after the parentheses defining the arguments, and `button id = list[i]` is a syntax error; it should be `button.id = list[i]`. Naming a variable list shadows the built-in `list` class.

Comment: Im sorry for the sloppy code example. Ive edited the code. Everything is within the same class MyScreen(Screen).

Comment: If I cant assign ids through python code, how is it possible to reference one specific widget of a bunch of dynamically created ones? Is there maybe another way then?

Comment: You can create your own dictionary of Buttons. Or you can explicitly add those Buttons to the `ids` dictionary yourself. Note that adding a hard reference to a widget in `ids` will prevent that widget from being garbage collected, which is why Kivy uses weak references instead.